# Linear maps: $A,B \in L(V,W)$: if $r(A)=r(B)$ then $B=SAT$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ and $W$ be finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Prove that for ever linear map $A$ and $B$ $\in L(V,W)$: if $r(A)=r(B)$ (rank) then there are linear maps $S$ and $T$ from $L(V,V)$ and $L(W,W)$ respectively, such that $B = SAT $
$\\$

(not sure if everyone uses the same notation, but $L(V,W)$ is a vector space of all linear maps that go from $V$ to $W$)

Now the idea for a proof was given such that you prove that for any linear map $C$ the following is true: if $\{z_1,...,z_r\}$ is a basis for $Im(C)$ and $v_1,...,v_r \in V$ chosen such that $C(v_i)=z_i$ for every $i \in \{1,...,r\}$. Show that $\{[v_1,...,v_r]\}$ is linearly independent set and that the vector space V is a direct sum of that set and $Ker(C)$.$\\$

Now that proof isn't all that complicated, assuming I managed to do it on my own, how would I apply that in solving the upper proof? I've thought about it for some time and I'm not quite certain how it's even related. Any hint would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r = \dim \operatorname{Im} B = \dim \operatorname{Im} A$.

Furthermore, let $w_1,\dots,w_r$ be a basis of $\operatorname{Im} B$ and $v_1,\cdots,v_r$ preimages such that $B(v_i) = w_i$ for $i = 1,\dots,r$. Note that the vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent (**Why?**). You can extend this set of linear independent vectors to a basis as $v_1,\dots,v_r, v_{r + 1},\dots, v_n$ for $n = \dim V$. (Here, I'm using the hint you formulated in your post)

Same for $A$. Let $w_1',\dots,w_r'$ be a basis of $\operatorname{Im} A$ and $v_1',\dots,v_r'$ their respective preimages.

Now define the map $T$ by setting $T(v_i) = v_i'$ for $i \leq r$ and $T(v_i) = 0$ (**Why does this give a well defined linear map?**). This gives you $A T(v_i) = A v_i' = w_i'$. Can you proceed from here? The mapping $S$ is constructed in a similar way.

Since you're a freshman, I set some questions in bold letters which you should ask yourself before going on with the proof.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer!! I figured everything out from there, really appreciate it!

Comment: @DomoB: You're welcome!